# Javascript replace method not working for me?

Tags: javascript

I have given code below which is not working for me? How to fix this.

***Below is the given code.***

```js
function nameValidate() {
  var name = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
  var status = document.getElementById("status");
  var regEx = /^([a-zA-Z]+\s)*+[a-zA-Z]+$/;
  if (name == "") {
    status.innerHTML = "Please enter name";
  } else if (!regEx.test(name)) {
    status.innerHTML = "Please enter valid input";
    name = name.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, ""); //this code not working for me How to fix this it not replace 
  } else {
    status.innerHTML = "Looks good!";
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="txtName">Full Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtName" oninput="nameValidate()" />
  <small id="status" class="text-form text-muted"></small>
</form>
```

Comment: When you say "does'nt work", do you mean that name has not the value you want or that the value of the txtName element is not updating ?

Comment: I want that when i put any other text like 0-9,symbols it should be replace by null or space. Means it not updating.

Comment: Yeah I understand the purpose of your regex but if you think that it will replace the *content of the input* its not like this. I wanted to know if you watch your name var if its also not good.

Answer (score 0):

First, correct your `regEx` variable to `regex`, then remove either the `*` asterisk character or the following `+` character as you cannot define `*` and `+` together. The `*` indicates that you expect zero or more characters and the `+` indicates that you expect at least one character or more.
When you use `*`, then `John`, `John Smith` and `John Adam Smith` is valid.
When you use `+`, then `John Smith` and `John Adam Smith` is valid but not `John` alone.

And if you want to replace the input value, you have to refer to the element and then to its `value` property.

```js
function nameValidate() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("txtName");
  var name = elem.value;
  var status = document.getElementById("status");
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z]+\s)*[a-zA-Z]+$/;
  if (name == "") {
    status.innerHTML = "Please enter name";
  } else if (!regex.test(name)) {
    status.innerHTML = "Please enter valid input";
    elem.value = name.replace(/[^a-z ]/gi, ""); //this code not working for me How to fix this it not replace 
  } else {
    status.innerHTML = "Looks good!";
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="txtName">Full Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtName" oninput="nameValidate()" />
  <small id="status" class="text-form text-muted"></small>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two mistake on it:

1- you declare a variable named regEx (Uppercase E) than you use regex in the else if clause.

2- your regEx is not a valid one because you cant chain an '+' after an '*'

it works that way (check what your actual regex is intended to test):

```js
function nameValidate() {
  var name = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
  var status = document.getElementById("status");
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z]+\s)*[a-zA-Z]+$/;
  if (name == "") {
    status.innerHTML = "Please enter name";
  } else if (!regex.test(name)) {
    status.innerHTML = "Please enter valid input";
    name = name.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, ""); //this code not working for me How to fix this it not replace 
  } else {
    status.innerHTML = "Looks good!";
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="txtName">Full Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtName" oninput="nameValidate()" />
  <small id="status" class="text-form text-muted"></small>
</form>
```

Comment: I have corrected my code. But still it can't work like i want. Just enter any other value other than alphabet. Still it takes 0-9,Symbols. I don't want numerical & Symbols in Name. Replace method not working for me.

Comment: You regex is still invalid an throws error; try the code i added in my comment it works and dosen't allow numerical or symbol !